# How could I run a MapReduce program in Java with testNG?

Tags: hadoop, testng

I have a MapReduce program based on Hadoop. I know how to run it with the command of ${hadoop_home}/bin/hadoop jar .

However, I want to run this program with testNG. What should I do to start a testNG case with hadoop?

Comment: Invoke your MapReduce job in an @Test method.

Comment: To start the @Test method, I use the command: $java -classpath=${class_path} org.testng.TestNG arg1 arg2 ...              The "java" command cannot start hadoop. That's my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a unit testing framework, look at [mr-unit (Apache)](http://mrunit.apache.org/). You can wrap the driver code in either JUnit or im assuming TestNG (disclaimer - I've only ever used JUnit).

This allows you to push values through a mapper or reducer and assert that particular output / counters came out

Comment: My question could be misleading. I am not going to test the MapReduce program itself, but the MR program is used to generate testing data for a test case.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out, the key point is the classpath setting.

Besides the **hadoop-core-.jar**, all jar files under **${hadoop_home}/share/hadoop/lib/**, jar files under **${hadoop_home}/share/hadoop/lib/jsp-/**, and other jar files the program code depend on, "${hadoop.home}/conf", **"${hadoop.home}/share/hadoop"** and the MR program itself must been compiled and packed as a Jar file and added into runtime class path.

After such setting finished, testNG test cases invoking the MR method could be run by the regular way.